# git: reverting a merge when there are later commits

Tags: git

I merged into the main master branch of my  git tree a feature that was half-baked. Later, I made a couple of commits in "master" that affected completely unrelated files. All of this has been pushed to remote as well.

Now I want to revert the changes made in that half-baked feature, but without losing the later commits. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) the files affected by the half baked feature to the commit before you merged.

```
# find the commit hash with 
git log
# checkout those files to the commit you want
git checkout c5f567 -- file1/to/restore file2/to/restore
# commit to master
```

Comment: I just did that, but it doesn't seem to do anything. The affected files are still in their "affected" state. I want them to be reverted to how they were in "master", before being merged.

Comment: If they are still in their affected state then you didn't check them out to a healthy commit. Did you run `git checkout` or did you run `git checkout <hash> -- file1/to/restore file2/to/restore`? Did you check them out to a commit that is far enough back (before the merge?)

Comment: I did the second... but wait. Now I realise that I have to check them out to the previous commit to the merge, not the one of the merge. Sorry; I'll try again.

Comment: *You can checkout the files affected by the half baked feature to the commit before you merged.*